# make a dictionary and search by property

Tags: javascript

how can i make a dictionary function that returns the meaning of a word... for example

this is the dictionary, a simple object that has properties or words with meanings,

```
var dictionary=
{
    'locomoción':
    {
        means:'Traslado de un lugar a otro.',
    }
}
```

this is the function that have to return the meaning of a word for example, i have to search for the meaning of 'locomocion', the function have to return 'Traslado de un... bla bla bla'

```
exports.diccionario=function(key)
{
    //search by object property
    //if(dictionary[key] exists) returns dictionary[key].means;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator to check for existence:

```
var key = 'locomocion';

if (key in dictionary) {
  return dictionary[key].means;
}
```